Create new column in df based on membership of values from another column in a dictionary
Python 3.12.3
Polars 1.8.2
Polars-lts-cpu: 1.10.0
OS: Linux-lite 24.04 VM
I have the following code:
import polars as pl

countries = ['usa', 'france', 'japan', 'brazil', 'new_zealand']
calling_codes = [1, 33, 81, 55, 64]

df = pl.DataFrame({'country': countries, 'calling_code': calling_codes })

capitals_dict = {'usa':'washington_dc', 'france': 'paris', 'brazil': 'brasilia'}

I would like to create a new column called capital in df that gets filled from the values in capitals_dict if the country that is found in df['country'] is in the keys of capitals_dict.
I have tried using replace:
df.with_columns(capital = pl.col('country').replace(capitals_dict))

shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ country     ┆ calling_code ┆ capital       │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ str         ┆ i64          ┆ str           │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ usa         ┆ 1            ┆ washington_dc │
│ france      ┆ 33           ┆ paris         │
│ japan       ┆ 81           ┆ japan         │
│ brazil      ┆ 55           ┆ brasilia      │
│ new_zealand ┆ 64           ┆ new_zealand   │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘

But it will fill the rows for japan and new_zealand with the country name. How would I go about assigning a default value for countries not in the capitals_dict but in the countries and calling_codes lists?
So that I get something like this instead:
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ country     ┆ calling_code ┆ capital       │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ str         ┆ i64          ┆ str           │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ usa         ┆ 1            ┆ washington_dc │
│ france      ┆ 33           ┆ paris         │
│ japan       ┆ 81           ┆ [default]     │ # <-
│ brazil      ┆ 55           ┆ brasilia      │
│ new_zealand ┆ 64           ┆ [default]     │ # <-
└─────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘


replace should work - perhaps you can show your attempt and what went wrong. It also helps if you can include what the final result should be.

Sounds like replace_strict if you want to provide a default - I have edited the answer below.

Depending on the goal, there are 2 replace functions:

.replace()
.replace_strict()

If you want to keep the original value for a non-match, you can use replace
df.with_columns(capital = pl.col("country").replace(capitals_dict))

shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ country     ┆ calling_code ┆ capital       │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ str         ┆ i64          ┆ str           │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ usa         ┆ 1            ┆ washington_dc │
│ france      ┆ 33           ┆ paris         │
│ japan       ┆ 81           ┆ japan         │ # non-match unchanged
│ brazil      ┆ 55           ┆ brasilia      │
│ new_zealand ┆ 64           ┆ new_zealand   │ # non-match unchanged
└─────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘

If you want to replace with a value of a different dtype, or if you want a default value for "non-matches" - you can use replace_strict
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("country").replace_strict(capitals_dict, default="NOT FOUND")
     .alias("capital")
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ country     ┆ calling_code ┆ capital       │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ str         ┆ i64          ┆ str           │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ usa         ┆ 1            ┆ washington_dc │
│ france      ┆ 33           ┆ paris         │
│ japan       ┆ 81           ┆ NOT FOUND     │
│ brazil      ┆ 55           ┆ brasilia      │
│ new_zealand ┆ 64           ┆ NOT FOUND     │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘


It's the DataFrames.join() method you need to use. I grabbed your code and here's what I came up with:
>>> import polars as pl

>>> countries = ["usa", "france", "brazil"]
>>> calling_codes = [1, 33, 55]
>>> capitals = ["washington_dc", "paris", "brasilia"]

>>> df = pl.DataFrame({'country': countries, 'calling_code': calling_codes })
>>> df
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬──────────────┐
│ country ┆ calling_code │
│ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ i64          │
╞═════════╪══════════════╡
│ usa     ┆ 1            │
│ france  ┆ 33           │
│ brazil  ┆ 55           │
└─────────┴──────────────┘

>>> df_capitals = pl.DataFrame({"country": countries, "capital": capitals})
>>> df.join(df_capitals, on='country')
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ country ┆ calling_code ┆ capital       │
│ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ str     ┆ i64          ┆ str           │
╞═════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ usa     ┆ 1            ┆ washington_dc │
│ france  ┆ 33           ┆ paris         │
│ brazil  ┆ 55           ┆ brasilia      │
└─────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘

You could also create df_capitals this way:
>>> capitals = {"usa": "washington_dc", "france": "paris", "brazil": "brasilia"}
>>> df_capitals =  pl.DataFrame({"country": capitals.keys(), "capital": capitals.values()})
>>> df_capitals
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬───────────────┐
│ country ┆ capital       │
│ ---     ┆ ---           │
│ str     ┆ str           │
╞═════════╪═══════════════╡
│ usa     ┆ washington_dc │
│ france  ┆ paris         │
│ brazil  ┆ brasilia      │
└─────────┴───────────────┘

